# ddev/docker fails with "Failed programming external connectivity", Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, ddev

ddev gets this nasty error in `ddev start` (Windows 10, Docker for Windows 18.03)

ERROR: for ddev-xxx-db  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint ddev-sanjacinto-db (313d966276870feb88b89ec7ab8f34ec9c876cfe165ff45185fa725fdbbd7f70): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:32777:tcp:172.18.0.2:3306: input/output error

Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've seen this many times, only on Windows, and have always been able fix it with:

- `ddev poweroff`
- Restarting docker if necessary

There are lots of answers on the internet, I think the most important open issue is with docker-compose here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3277

Comment: I have never had this issue with plain docker-compose setups. I now see it for the first time since I have started using ddev. My plain docker setup can be found here: https://github.com/Tuurlijk/docker-local

Comment: Edited; I haven't seen this much lately with recent Docker Desktop for Windows, but when I have, `ddev poweroff` has fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

[docker description](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/)

> On Windows systems, CTRL+C does not stop the container. So, first type
>   CTRL+C to get the prompt back (or open another shell), then type
>   docker container ls to list the running containers, followed by docker
>   container stop  to stop the container.
>   Otherwise, you get an error response from the daemon when you try to
>   re-run the container in the next step.

I had the same problem, I thought with CTRL+C stoped the container but it was not the case, any af the answer above works because they all stop containers, restarting docker or stoping container explicity.

I prefer:

```
docker container ls #list containers running
docker stop [container id] #replace [container id] with the container id running
```